# Compound Proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let the three propositional variables $p$ and $q$ be $x < 0$ and $x < 3$.

If we have this inequality $0< x < 3$ and we need to transform this inequality symbolically, the answer will be $p\wedge q$?

If yes, why the answer is not $\neg p\wedge q$?

Comment: In fact, it is not possible to express the proposed relation based on the given sentences. Are you sure $p(x) = x < 0$? It might be the case that $p(x) = x > 0$.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia , Yes  , thats why I am asking . it should be x >0 , is that right ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Yes; $ 0<x<3$ is a shorthand for  $0<x$ **and** $x<3$